# Windows 10 update appears to have broken GHC

Tags: haskell, windows-10, ghc

I have the latest [Haskell Platform (8.0.2)](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) and it appears that the forced update of Windows10 (1703) has broken GHC. There is a ticket ([#13411](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13411)) about this, and it seems like I need to [replace the gcc.exe](https://github.com/Mistuke/ghc-compat#readme) file in my build.

Where do I find the appropriate gcc.exe file and where do I put it (assuming standard installation of the Haskell Platform)?

Comment: Editorial Note: These forced windows updates are nothing but trouble!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC should be in `mingw\bin` in your installation directory, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
```

The appropriate binary can be found in your linked repository. The one meant for GHC 8.0.X should suite you fine. Be sure to use the `x64` one if you've installed the 64bit variant of the platform, and `x86` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

As of 20 April 2017 1700 UTC this seems like the process:

- Download the [version of GHC 8.0.2](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/ghc-8.0.2-x86_64-unknown-mingw32-win10.tar.xz) with the Windows 10 patch ([As described here.](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2017-April/014131.html)).
- Open the archive file.  Windows 10's native archive browser does not understand the .tar.xz format so you will need something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open it.
- Find the "`gcc.exe`" file under `\ghc-8.0.2\mingw\bin\` and copy it over the file in `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\bin\`.